# Installing libreoffice on SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 12

Tags: linux, rpm, sles

I have a server with a newly installed SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 12. It appears that the libreoffice related RPM's are missing, and instead are part of SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop. What's the best way to go about installing it? Can I build RPM's for SLES based on the SRPM's for SLED, or will it wind up being easier to compile from source? I just want to run libreoffice in 'headless' mode to convert doc's to pdf's, but there are a lot of dependencies.